# A question on smooth functions and the Taylor series

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, smooth-manifolds

I've been reading Wald's general relativity book and at the end of chapter 2 (question 2) he asks the reader to prove the following expression (multivariable Taylor series) by induction and I'm unsure how to proceed.
Let $F\in\mathscr{F}(M)$ be a smooth (i.e. $C^{\infty}$) function defined on an $n$-dimensional manifold, then it can be expressed as the following infinite series $$F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x^{i}-a^{i})H_{i}(x)$$ where $x=(x^{1},\ldots,x^{n})$, $a=(a^{1},\ldots,a^{n})$ and $H_{i}(x)$ satisfies $$H_{i}(a)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{i}}\bigg\vert_{x=a}.$$
I think I can do the first step. For $n=1$ we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to write $$F(x)=F(a)+\int_{a}^{x} F'(s)ds$$ and through a change of variables, $s=t(x-a)+a$, which linearly rescales the integration interval from $[a,x]$ to $[0,1]$. Then we have that $ds=(x-a)dt$ and $$F(x)=F(a)+(x-a)\int_{0}^{1}F'(t(x-a)+a)dt=F(a)+(x-a)H_{1}$$
which is the expression that he gives as a hint for $n=1$ (although it'd be nice to be able to prove this expression too really). From this we see that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\bigg\vert_{x=a}=H_{1}(a)$$ as required.
I'm unsure how to proceed after the induction step though?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your puzzlement is well-founded: read these [notes](http://stockage.univ-brest.fr/~scott/Physics/my_notes_on_Wald1984.pdf) p. 10 (top).

The statement is the so-called [Hadamard's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_lemma), a consequence of the FTC and the chain rule (one cannot understand Wald's *induction* hint). Read the wiki proof and you are done.

By the way note that the equation (2.2.2) in Wald's book, p. 16 (ed. 1984), doesn't contain an infinite series (you have to change $\infty$ with $\,n$).

Finally read [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/pierce/mat218/PS5.pdf), p. 4 (bottom), a more general statement.

Comment: Cheers, really appreciate the links you've added. I'm glad I'm not just being completely stupid!